# Energy as a function on tangent bundle

Tags: smooth-manifolds, classical-mechanics, invariance, tangent-bundle

I've been reading the [Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eleontak/CM.pdf) book by Leon A. Takhtajan. On p. 15 (which is p. 29 in the PDF file), he introduces the *energy* $E = \sum_i \dot q^i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^i} - L$ of a Lagrangian system and claims that $E$ is well defined as a function from $TM \times \mathbb{R}$, where $M$ is the configuration space, $TM$ is the tangent bundle, and $\mathbb R$ the time axis. To "prove" this, he takes two arbitrary charts on $M$ (as opposed to $TM$) and the corresponding coordinate transformation $\mathbf{q'} = F(\mathbf{q})$. He extends $F$ to a coordinate transformation on $TM$ using the tangent map $F_*$ and concludes that the energy $E$ is invariant under the extended transformation, and so the function $E: TM \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is well defined since the result does not depend on the coordinate representation of the argument.

Problem is: THIS IS NOT A PROOF, as it only proves the claim for one special case. Should we be starting with an arbitrary coordinate transformation on $TM \times \mathbb{R}$ instead?

I tried to find an answer online but couldn't. So, my questions are:

1. Is $E$ really well defined as a function on $TM \times \mathbb{R}$, as the book claims?
2. Is there an online source that gives the correct proof of this fact?

To simplify the question: I am aware that the Lagrangian $L: TM\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is well defined, so it's the sum $\sum_i \dot q^i \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^i}$ that worries me.

Comment: No, this is a valid proof.  $\dot q\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}$ only make sense if you work in a local trivialization of $TM$ asssociated to a coordinate chart of $M$.

Comment: @user10354138, if this is a valid proof, then this would imply that any coordinate transformation on $TM$ is induced by one on $M$. Does it have to be that way, though, given that $TM$ is a manifold in its own right?  In particular, why does such a transformation have to act linearly on the fibers? Not every $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ function is linear, right? This gotta have something to do with the fact that these are tangent vectors, but I'm missing the link.

Comment: @user10354138, I forgot to mention that even if everything else is correct, the proof doesn't take the time component into account. $TM \times \mathbb{R}$ is what we are dealing with here, not $TM$.